# how to get both values call in function javascript

Tags: javascript, html

please check my code i tried to get both values from different drop down menus.

```
<select name="select1" onchange="updatevariable(data1,select2)"> 
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="15" >15</option>  
</select>

<select name="select2" onchange="updatevariable(select1,data2)"> 
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="23" >23</option> 
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = "test";
    var value1 = "test";
    function updatevariable(data1,data2) { 
        value = data1;
        value1 = data2;
        alert(value,value1);
    } 
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing JS variables that don't exist: `data1`, `data2`, `select`, `select2`

You don't need to pass any variables into the function. Try this instead:

Updated HTML with `id` specified on each `select`

```
<select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="updatevariable(this)"> 
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="15" >15</option>  
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2" onchange="updatevariable(this)"> 
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="23" >23</option> 
</select>
```

And your JS function:

```
window.updatevariable = function(el) { 
    value = document.getElementById('select1').value;
    value1 = document.getElementById('select2').value;

    alert(value +' | ' + value1);
}
```

### [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bLJHV/1/)

Comment: Why are you passing `this` to the function from the `onchange` event, but never utilizing `el`?

Comment: I passed `this` from habit. I didn't utilize `el` in the function because that would complicate things. One wouldn't know if `el` was referencing `select1` or `select2`. So it's easier to get each by `ID`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Explanation:

What you have is called inline script, it should be avoided. You could replace all your code with this under instead. In your html what you want to do doesn't work that way. `updatevariable(data1,select2)` does not get the variable or the select element. So try my solution instead.

```
var value = "test";
var value1 = "test";
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
function updatevariable() {
    value = sel[0].value;
    value1 = sel[1].value;
    alert(value +' - '+ value1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].addEventListener('change', updatevariable);
};
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8UX8/)

You could also use jQuery or Mootools if you have much code to write. Otherwise just plain JS is good also...

Comment: You don't have to call the function in html. Plus you should add explanation for OP to understand what's going on

Comment: @Ani, added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="updatevariable(1,select1)"> 
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="15" >15</option>  
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" onchange="updatevariable(2,select2)"> 
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="23" >23</option> 
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var values = new Array();
    function updatevariable(index,id) { 
        var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        values[index] = value;
    } 
</script>
```